# PHP error, outputs else when should be logging in

Tags: php

Does anyone know whats wrong with this?, the else is echo'd even if credentials are correct

```
include("includes/dbconn.php");
// username and password sent from form 
$username=$_POST['username']; 
$password=$_POST['password']; 

$sql=("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE email ='.$username.' and password='.$password.'");
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

if($count==1){

    session_register("username");
    session_register("password"); 
    header("location:login_success.php");

} else {
    echo "Wrong Username or Password";
}
```

Comment: Please stop storing plain text passwords also this query is completely open to attack.

Comment: can u post ur dbconn.php file???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `else` section is executing because your query had failed. Remove the unnecessary brackets from the query. Also you are appending the values incorrectly. As you are enclosing the query within brackets, there is no need of appending it again.

So change your query

```
$sql=("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE email ='.$username.' and password='.$password.'");
```

to

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM customers WHERE email ='$username' and password='$password'";
```

Comment: theses are the least of the problems here

Comment: please don't this is the worst approach to take

Comment: @Dagon what do you mean?

Comment: plain text password no user variable sanitation - its security 101

Comment: @Dagon i got your point brother, but this post solved the problem. So this deserves a upvote. Also now we can tell Ellis how to implement security issues. :)

Comment: @Dagon.. I just helped Ellis to solve the issue. Anyway even if password is not encrypted the query should work first no?

Comment: guys..I don't care even if no one accepts/upvote my answer. I am glad to help Ellis.

Comment: @dagon  this was for a school project anyway and wasnt to be implemented upon a real application storing actuall information on users